# Date parsing in Pandas from a pdf

Tags: pandas

I am totally new to Pandas and not managing. I have a pdf (in German) with my working schedule and I would like to read it into pandas, format the date, save it as a csv so I can import it into some calendar (google calendar or whatever). I am using pd.to_datetime and my problem is that I cannot parse the Start Date column to a standard date format.

This is the format that I have:

```
Start Date        Start Time    End Time    Location    Subject
Do., 10. Mai 2018   10:00        11:40        Spain     Klettern
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`dateparser` module](https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as it should do a good job with these:

```
In [1]: 
import dateparser
s = "Do., 10. Mai 2018"
dateparser.parse(s).date()

Out[1]: datetime.date(2018, 5, 10)
```